# tr link with php code inside

Tags: javascript, php, html-table, tablerow

I'm trying to do something a little weird and I'm kind of lost.

I have this code:

```
<tr onclick="href='<?php if (isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])){ echo 'logado.php?'; } else { echo 'index.php?'; } ?>grupo=<?php echo $row_buscainterna['id_grupo']; ?>'">
```

My `<tr>` are in hover, so when the user clicks it I would like to perform this "php action"
Can't make it work. Can somebody help me?

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like to use code like this:

```
<tr onclick="window.location.href='<?php if (isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])){ echo 'logado.php?'; } else { echo 'index.php?'; } ?>grupo=<?php echo $row_buscainterna['id_grupo']; ?>'">
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3whmy/1/)

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be easier to put a link inside your tr tag, and style it to make it the size of the tr.

Comment: but my problem it's not "visual", the link doesn't work.
I need it to "read" the php action.

Can you sample your idea? ^^

Comment: The link doesn't work because you didn't write a correct javascript code. And I think a link can be easier, you don't need to use javascript for a link

Comment: I've just missed the "window.location" stuff... but thanks anyway! ^^

Answer (score 1):

OnClick attribute should contain javascript code. Your example sets global variable `href`  to some URL.

If you want to send the user to this URL, then you shoud use `document.location` instead of `href`:

```
<tr onclick="document.location='<?php if (isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])){ echo 'logado.php?'; } else { echo 'index.php?'; } ?>grupo=<?php echo $row_buscainterna['id_grupo']; ?>'">
```